# C# Wait for user input to continue with function

Tags: c#, function, dialog, panel

I have a function where I need user input to do A or B.

`if(userinput == "Confirm"){A}
else {B}`

My question: Do I have to use dialogs, or may I use a panel with the message and two buttons for this?

What I have: Panel with textbox (message) and two buttons (confirm, cancel)

If yes, How may I accomplish that?
If no, how do I even use dialogs? (just point out a link)

(if you don't get my point so far, keep reading)

> 1) User fills a form
>
> 2) If that field is not unique on the database, it just get validated to be compatible with it
>
> 3) If that field is unique, or a primary key, however, it searches the database for the information connected to it
>
> 4) After getting that information, it checks if any other field built for that intel, is filled or empty
>
> 5) If that form has anything in it that the user has inserted, the system has to ask if it updates the form with the intel it just got, or if it fills only the empty fields, and keeps those which are not empty.
>
> 6) The function continues validating

Answer (score 0):

You can use forms and manage `DialogResult` value. For doing that you have to make a new form where you want user to input. Then manage this way:

```
YourForm form = new YourForm();

if(form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    MessageBox.Show("This is the input" + form.textBox1.Text)
}
```

More help in here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hmmm... Could I wait for a button click? Like... Function stops until the user clicks one of those two buttons

Comment: Yes. Set DialogResult property of the button to the desired value

Comment: my problem is... I don't have a different form... I have a panel for that purpose on the actual form where the function runs...

Comment: for some reason, if i use your code, replacing "form" with "this", it just does nothing. I've set the dialogresult on both buttons

Comment: if you use this you will be referencing to your actual form and not to the one you ll try to open

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have 2 buttons in your new form :

```
Button okButton = new Button();
Button cancelButton = new Button();
```

Assign click event for them :

```
okButton.Click += OnClick;
cancelButton.Click += OnClick;
```

Then inside your `OnClick()` method :

```
void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(sender == okButton)
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Ok;

    this.Close();
}
```

Now you can use it like:

```
if(new MeForm().ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // user clicked OK
}
else
{
    // user clicked cancel
}
```